# Hash table related syntax errors in an AWK script?

Tags: awk, syntax-error, hashtable

I'm running into these two syntax errors when attempting to run the AWK script included below:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 30 source file test.awk
 context is
      dealer_schedule[last_name] = >>>  [ <<< date, time, am_pm, first_name, last_name]
awk: illegal statement at source line 30 source file test.awk
awk: syntax error at source line 33 source file test.awk
```

I'm using awk version 3.4 on Ubuntu Linux. This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {

  # Initialize the hash table to store the dealer schedule.
  dealer_schedule = assoc()

  # Initialize the hash table to store the number of times that Mylie was playing with each unique dealer.
  dealer_counts = assoc()

  # Read the Mylie player information file.
  mylie_info = read_mylie_info_file()

}

{
  # Get the date field from the first four characters of the file name.
  date = substr(FILENAME, 1, 4)

  # Split the input line into an array of fields.
  fields = split($0, fields, "|")

  # Get the time, AM/PM label, first name, and last name of the roulette dealer.
  time = fields[2]
  am_pm = fields[3]
  first_name = fields[4]
  last_name = fields[5]

  # Add the data to the dealer schedule hash table.
  dealer_schedule[last_name] = [date, time, am_pm, first_name, last_name]

  # For each time that Mylie was playing, increment the count for the dealer.
  for (i in mylie_info) {
    if ((date == mylie_info[i][0]) and (time == mylie_info[i][1]) and (am_pm == mylie_info[i][2])) {
      if (last_name in dealer_counts) {
        dealer_counts[last_name]++
      } else {
        dealer_counts[last_name] = 1
      }
    }
  }
}

END {
  # Print the number of times that Mylie was playing with each unique dealer to a separate txt file.

  print "dealer,count" > "Notes_Dealer_Analysis.txt"

  for (dealer in dealer_counts) {
    print dealer, dealer_counts[dealer] >> "Notes_Dealer_Analysis.txt"
  }

  # Print the 5 column dealer schedule for the times that Mylie was playing.

  print "date,time,am_pm,first_name,last_name" > "Dealers_working_during_losses.txt"

  for (dealer in dealer_schedule) {
    for (i in dealer_schedule[dealer]) {
      # Check if the dealer was working at the same time as Mylie was playing.
      if ((dealer_schedule[dealer][i][0] == mylie_info["date"]) and (dealer_schedule[dealer][i][1] == mylie_info["time"]) and (dealer_schedule[dealer][i][2] == mylie_info["am_pm"])) {
        print dealer_schedule[dealer][i][0], dealer_schedule[dealer][i][1], dealer_schedule[dealer][i][2], dealer_schedule[dealer][i][3], dealer_schedule[dealer][i][4] >> "Dealers_working_during_losses.txt"
      }
    }
  }

  # Close the Mylie player information file.
  mylie_info_file.close()

}

function read_mylie_info_file() {

  # Read the Mylie player information file.

  mylie_info = assoc()

  mylie_info_file = open("Mylie.txt", "r")

  for (line in mylie_info_file) {
    fields = split(line, fields, "|")

    date = fields[1]

    time = fields[2]

    am_pm = fields[3]

    mylie_info[i] = [date, time, am_pm]
  }

  mylie_info_file.close()

  return mylie_info

}
```

I've tried various ways of using different syntax constructs that should work in various versions of awk including this one. But my knowledge of awk scripting is a little too rusty for me to even know if I'm asking the right questions or looking in the right places.

Comment: awk doesn't automatically express variables like modern languages - that is, `last_name` is a variable, `$last_name` is the contents of the variable, and you want to index by the contents of the variable.

Comment: comment states this - `dealer_schedule = assoc()` - is suppoed to initialize a *`hash table`*; where did you get this from? in my `awk` this says to call the (user-defined) function named `assoc` and assign its return value to the (`awk`) scalar varaible named `dealer_schedule`

Comment: `dealer_schedule[last_name] = [date, time, am_pm, first_name, last_name]` is an invalid assignment statement (eg, the `[` and `]` on the right side of the `=` are not valid syntax); based on later references (eg, `dealer_schedule[dealer][i][0]`) I'm guessing that you're actually trying to populate a 2nd dimension of the `dealer_schedule` array but ... *a)* this is not how you populate the 2nd dimension of an array and *b)* `dealer_schdule[dealer][i][0]` is attempting to reference the 3rd dimension of the array (but you never populate a 3rd dimension)

Comment: `fields = split($0, fields, "|")` says to split the input line (`$0`) on the pipe delimiter (`|`) and populate the `fields[]` array with the results ... it also says to assign the count/number of array entries (ie, output from the `split()` function call) to the scalar variable named `fields`; this should be generating a fatal error stating that `fields` cannot be used as both a scalar variable and an array variable

Comment: there are several other (fatal) errors/issues with this code; net result: this is nowhere near to what could be called a valid `awk` script; it appears you've taken the syntax from some other language and tried to shoe-horn it into what you *think*  an `awk` script should look like; whatever you're trying to do in `awk` ... this isn't how you do it ... you'll have to start over from scratch, starting with reading up on (valid) `awk` syntax

Comment: There are way too many basic syntax errors here. Try to learn enough Awk by writing a much simpler script first, just to learn the syntax. There are many good basic tutorials; see the [Stack Overflow `awk` tag info page](/tags/awk/info) for some links.

Comment: @JohnBayko regarding ["`last_name` is a variable, `$last_name` is the contents of the variable,"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247371/hash-table-related-syntax-errors-in-an-awk-script#comment136182661_77247371) - no, you may be thinking of shell rather than awk as that'd be true of shell but in awk to get the contents of a variable you just use it's name `last_name`, just like in C, python, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is weird mix of GNU `AWK` syntax and `python` syntax, haphazard collection of parts of programming language from 1986 and unrelated programming language from 1991 has little chance to work at all, not saying about desired output.

```
awk: syntax error at source line 30 source file test.awk
...
dealer_schedule[last_name] = [date, time, am_pm, first_name, last_name]
```

This particular line uses list literal. GNU `AWK` has not lists, only associative [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), which are rough equivalent of python's dicts. You would need to express it as array with keys being numbers. You would also need to be more implicit as GNU `AWK` has not Array literal as far as I know, so if `python` you might do something like

```
x = {0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"}
```

in GNU `AWK` would require

```
x[0]="a";x[1]="b";x[2]="c"
```

Generally you might either try to bent this code into correct `python` code or bent this code into correct GNU `AWK` code, but firstly consult rules of your organization to check if one of these tools is not verboten.

Comment: In any awk including GNU that'd be `split("a b c",x)`. If a 2d array was required then in GNU awk it'd be `x[0][1]; split("a b c",x[0])`. In reality `x[]` should start at `1` instead of `0` in awk to conform with all generated arrays. You're right, no awk has array literals.